# PowerApp/SharePoint Vs .NET/SharePoint Vs .NET/SQL

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, architecture

We want to start a new project for managing ISO process documents with approvals and custom permissions. the system need to have the following main characteristics :-

1. Secure the back-end
2. Server-side and Client side validation

now we have 3 approaches to develop the system:-

1. PowerApp/SharePoint
2. .NET/SharePoint
3. .NET/SQL

now i found the following prons & Cons for each approach:-

1. PowerApp/SharePoint

- Pros

  - fast development
  - built-in connectors
- Cons

  - user can access the SharePoint lists directly and bypass and validation on power apps
  - Power apps validations and formulas do not apply on the server, they only provide client side validation

2. .NET/SharePoint

- Pros

  - we can secure the SharePoint lists to only be accessible by a Azure AD app, and define the business logic using a server-side technology (.net)
  - we can define the client side validation using java/script
- Cons

  - can not find any drawbacks only that it needs more time for development

3. .NET/SQL

- Pros

  - we can secure the back-end and access the SQL using a service account
  - we can define server-side & client-side validations
- Cons

  - more time to develop
  - we will need to create a document management system from scratch

so can anyone advice on this ? am i pointing out the pros and cons correctly? or i am missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have identified some of the key pros and cons of each approach. In general, using PowerApps and SharePoint can provide a fast development experience and built-in connectors, but it may not be as secure because users can access the SharePoint lists directly. Using .NET and SharePoint can provide better security, but it may take longer to develop. Using .NET and SQL can also provide good security, but it will take even longer to develop and require building a document management system from scratch.

One potential drawback of using .NET and SharePoint that you didn't mention is that it may be more difficult to customize and extend compared to using PowerApps and SharePoint. PowerApps provides a visual, drag-and-drop interface for building custom applications, whereas using .NET and SharePoint would require more programming experience.

Ultimately, the best approach will depend on your specific requirements, development resources, and timeline. It may be worth considering a combination of approaches, such as using PowerApps for the user interface and .NET for the back-end logic, to take advantage of the strengths of each. It may also be worth consulting with an experienced developer or systems integrator to help determine the best approach for your project.

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply.. but i am not sure how i can follow this appraoch `as using PowerApps for the user interface and .NET for the back-end logic`??